# Are there lockers in Gangnam Station?

Tags: south-korea, luggage-storage, seoul

I will be travelling to Seoul soon and am planning to visit the infamous Gangnam area. I would probably have heavy luggage with me so I am looking for a solution to store them. Are there lockers in Gangnam Station or near there? What are the approximate prices?

Edit: I had a look on Google for sure, but most of the information seems old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subway stations on [line 1-4](http://global.gangnam.go.kr/global/cts/view.do?pcode=GTS003&uId=111&menuNo=110065&lang=en) had lockers for a long time and Gangnam is line 2 (and [line 5-8](http://english.seoul.go.kr/subway-stations-lines-5-8-now-equipped-convenient-smart-lockers/) got the lockers in 2015). The small ones are 1500, the medium ones are 2000 and the large ones are 3000.[image]

Source: this [video](https://youtu.be/LRSFeh6JoDc) which explains how to use them even if you don't speak korean.